# Is there a name for a part of a recorded song where the music has ended and a spoken audio recording is played?

Tags: transcription

I'm transcribing a song, and towards the end of it the music cuts out and an audio recording of the album's producer telling an anecdote plays. It's entirely raw, i.e., no effects or instruments playing (at least to my ears). Is there a name for a part like this of a song?

In case it is useful, the song in question is The About It Song by Soulwax.

Comment: In opera, assuming it's part of the performance,  it's  "recitative" .  Not exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'spoken word outro' sounds right. It has been used before in this context ([link](https://www.reddit.com/r/indieheads/comments/6y0sl3/james_murphy_wanted_a_spoken_word_outro_by/)).

As far as I know there doesn't exist a canonical word or phrase that one would find in a musical textbook.

Answer (score 5):

There's no accepted name for it that I've ever heard.  Just describe it in plain English.  'Spoken outro' would do. Can't see any point in adding the extra word 'word' making it 'Spoken word outro'.   There's not much you can speak but words.

Comment: 'Spoken word' is idiomatic, presumably as a reverse match to 'written word'.